# Java Code unable to delete file

Tags: java

My java code is unable to delete files on the the system hard drive.

Whenever `file.delete()` function is called, it returns `false`.
Any ideas, why that might be happening?

Comment: Which user is java running as?
Does that user have needed rights to delete the file?
Are you running an application or an applet?

Answer (score 15):

[`File.delete()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete%28%29) can fail to delete a file for many reasons including:

- you don't have correct permissions to delete the file
- the file represents a directory and the directory is not empty
- the file is locked by another process, (or even by the same process in say an unclosed `FileOutputStream`)
- the file doesn't exist

Comment: @Aaron Digulla: an unclosed file only causes a problem on some operating systems, such as Windows. On systems with Posix filesystem semantics, a file can always be unlinked even if it is open by something else.

Comment: A couple more possibilities are 1) that the file is on a device that has been mounted read-only, or 2) you were unfortunate enough to hit a disc I/O error.  (Neither are the case here, but for completeness sake ...)

Answer (score 5):

`File.delete()` can return `false` if you are trying to delete a directory that is not empty, or the named file simply doesn't exist at the time of the call.

(if there is a permission issue, a SecurityException is thrown)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in my code and found that the culprit was actually an unclosed FileInputStream. After closing that FIS my file deleted without any problems. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The usual reasons are insufficient permissions (although normally that would throw an exception), trying to delete a non-existant file or trying to delete a non-empty directory. Are you totally sure that you have permissions to delete the file you are trying to delete?

Answer (score 1):

Some process might be reading/writing the file, so that it is locked. Or then your process does not have permissions to delete the file. If the file is a directory, all files inside it must be deleted first before the directory can be deleted. And finally there is the situation that the file does not exist, so the delete method will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Windows? Use the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to search for all processes which keep a handle (lock) on the file (or if this is a directory on any file inside of it).

On Linux, use `fuser`.

Comment: Open files on Linux won't prevent the file from being unlinked.

Comment: You can also lock files on Linux but that's rarely used. Also, NFS mounts can prevent files from being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You might be trying to delete any file exists in C: Drive and on that you might not have the permissions to do so. Try to put it inside any other drive than C: and then run your code. Hope it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file is not currently is use:
For example i was trying to delete a file using

```
f2.delete()
```

But it was unable to do as i was using BufferReader,FileWriter,BufferWriter etc.Close all those and then try.

```
buffer.close()
writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having trouble to delete file using file.delete(), your problem is that the file is still open.
Close buffer reader
Close File Writer
and most important CLOSE THE FILE before file.delete(), otherwise it will not delete.
Enjoy.